# How to plot a special kind of plot in python

Tags: python

I have a function shown below in the code.
How do I plot the function so it will vary radially as the "func" but on the angle side it will be constant?

Its like plotting many sub-circles like the one below.

Thanks.

```py
import numpy as np

a = 0.819 * pow(10,-3)
b = 2.73 * pow(10,-3)
Vo = 11.27
# d_phi_d_rho=Vo/
rho = np.linspace(0.0645,0.215,1000)
func = (Vo / (np.log(b/a))).*(1./rho)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that in Python you can't use `.*` for vector multiplication like in Matlab. You just need to use `*` and it will work for NumPy arrays.

Comment: hello Matt any idia how to recreate such plot shown in the photo in phyton?Thanks.

Comment: I've added an example in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the plot using the NumPy and [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) Python packages. For example, you could do:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = 0.819e-3
b = 2.73e-3
Vo = 11.27

# create a grid in cartensian X-Y space
x = np.linspace(-0.215, 0.215, 1000)
y = np.linspace(-0.215, 0.215, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# get the radial distance over the grid
rho = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)

# calculate the function
func = (Vo / (np.log(b / a))) * (1.0 / rho)

# mask values below a certain radial distance
rhomin = 0.0645
mask = rho < rhomin
func[mask] = np.inf  # set to infinity

# mask values above a certain radial distance
mask = rho > 0.215
func[mask] = 0.0  # set to zero

# produce the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(func, extent=[x[0], x[-1], y[0], y[-1]])

fig.show()
```

which gives:

[image]